# Custom datepicker with kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, datepicker

Has anyone been able to modify the datepicker in android to have both date and time selector? I have searched far and wide and have not been able to find something. Google tasks has a very nice datepicker that looks like this:
[custom datepicker in google tasks app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yoxqt.jpg)

Comment: There are [several dozen open source date and time pickers](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/27?sort=created).

Answer (score 0):

Material Components library - in case you haven't checked out their implementation yet, they have a nice one that is similar to what you might be looking for (unfortunately no iOS implementation in the library, if that's something important to you):

https://material.io/components/date-pickers/android#date-pickers

[image]

You could always build a custom view that is partly composed of the material date picker as well if you wanted more functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Amin. I have seen this but I am not sure how I can modify it to include both date and time pickers in the same modal.